# Dynamic content projection with ngSwitch - Angular 11

Tags: angular

I'm having an hard time to project dynamic content into a sidebar component using ng-content and ngSwitch.

Here's my sidebar component:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
        <ng-content select=[header]></ng-content>
    </div>

    <ng-content select=[content]></ng-content>
</div>
```

And here's how I want the projection to take place:

```
<app-sidebar>
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="sidebarAction$ | async">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'settings'">
                <span header class="tui-text_body-l">
                    Settings
                </span>
                <app-settings content></app-settings>
            </ng-container> 

            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'other'">
                 <span header class="tui-text_body-l">
                    Other
                 </span>
                 <app-other content></app-other>
            </ng-container>
    </ng-container> 
</app-sidebar>
```

But unfortunately nothing gets projected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple *ng-content* directives, you need to identify where the content is project to.  You have specified attribute selectors (though not quoted), but nowhere are those attributes present in your transcluded content.

Wrap your selectors in quotes and add the attributes to your content and you should be in business.  In the example below, content should appear in the header section because I've added a header attribute to a new container element.  Please note, in this example the container with the switch is wrapped in another container.  I don't know if that's necessary, or if the header attribute can be placed on it.

**Sidebar**

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
        <ng-content select="[header]"></ng-content>
    </div>

    <ng-content select="[content]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

**Consumer Component**

```
<app-sidebar>
    <ng-container header> <!-- added attribute here! -->
        <ng-container [ngSwitch]="sidebarAction$ | async">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'settings'">
                <span class="tui-text_body-l">
                    Settings
                </span>
                <app-settings content></app-settings>
            </ng-container> 

            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'other'">
                 <span class="tui-text_body-l">
                    Other
                 </span>
                 <app-other content></app-other>
            </ng-container>
         </ng-container>
    </ng-container> 
</app-sidebar>
```

Comment: I added quotes but it still doesn't work. Maybe you didn't see but I already have selectors! I only want the inner parts to be displayed.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't see them and I took them out.  You don't need to have the multiple selectors inside of the switch.  Not content will be rendered outside the switch since everything is inside ng-container.